# Projectile command for debug and release

Tags: projectile, compile

My google searches aren't turning up anything useful, but I am trying to figure out how I" can use projectile-project-compilation-cmd to be able to dynamically switch between release and debug with cmake, ie I would like to be able to somehow do a theoretical projectile-project-compilation-cmd-debug, projectile-project-compilation-cmd-release, but I have no idea how to go about doing this.

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `projectile-test-project` (bound to `C-p p P`) as your debug command and `projectile-compile-project` (bound to `C-p p c`) as your release command.

`projectile-toggle-between-implementation-and-test` (bound to `C-p p t`) also seems promising but I haven't used this yet, so I can't help you set this up.